# facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog is not showing image on share dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I have recently upgraded a Cordova app from V2.9 to V3.5, 
I am trying to share a link to facebook in a cordova app but Dialog is not showing image in the share dialog.

Plugin used : https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

**Code:**

```
facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog({
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'http://example.com'
}, function(response){});
```

**og metatags at example.com**

```
<meta property="og:image" content="path to logo.jpg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example2.com" />
```

**there are no og metatags at example2.com**

**Problem**

facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog is not showing image in the dialog since in between last month.

**Findings**

Dialog is getting title and description from the example2.com and as there is no og:image tag there, dialog is not showing any picture.

Plugin is making call to v2.2 API of the FB graph API while our FB App in facebook is V1.0

Old cordova App is making call to V1.0 API of the FB Graph and it is also not showing the picture now.

There is a or:url in a metatag of the example.com which points to example2.com and I have no access to change the og:url.

**Question**

What is causing the problem, is it FB Graph API update or og:url and if it is og:url, then how was it working before?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you use the PhoneGap plugin specific methods:

- https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin#show-a-dialog

IMHO, the code should be

```
facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog({
    method: "feed",
    link: "http://example.com",
    caption: "Such caption, very feed."
}, function(success) { }, function(error) { });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the image from url
First ensure that the page example.com has the image on the page
the do this  your code should work Note that where the page has more than one image the user
may be prompted to select one.

Good luck

```
facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog({
 method: 'feed',
 link: 'http://example.com',
}, function(response){});
```

You can also post the same issues here
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues

and someone will help you out ASAP